# Why is the hash considering the same value for every new temp file created for the input file in the API call?

Tags: python, flask

I have an API call which takes file input from the form and generates the hash key for the temporary file created. But again when a different file is selected as input file, the same hash is getting generated.Code snippet of the API call is below: (excluded other unrelated code)

```
 def gen_hash():
     for attr, document in request.files.iteritems():
            orig_filename = document.filename
            new_doc = add_doc(orig_filename, orig_filename)
            #mhash = None
            ##############
            # hashing algorithm checks the contents of the file if
            # modified before uploading to destination, NOT file name
            try:
                tmp1 = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
                tmp1.write(document.read())
                tmp1.seek(0)
                # for chunk in iter(lambda: tmp1.read(128* sha1().block_size),
                #                   b""):
                for chunk in iter(lambda: tmp1.read(128), b""):
                    sha1().update(chunk)
                mhash1 = sha1().hexdigest()
                print mhash1
            finally:
                #print e
                os.unlink(tmp1.name)
```

Using flask v.0.12, python 2.7. Why is the hash key same for the different file contents?

Comment: `tmp1.flush()`  before `tmp1.seek(0)` ? Do not delete the temp file and check if the data was received correct.

Comment: What is `sha1()` ? Likely `sha1().update(chunk)` creates a new sha object, updates it, then discards it. `mhash1 = sha1().hexdigest()` creates a new, empty sha object and gets its digest. You always the the digest of an empty buffer so its always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hashlib.sha1()` creates a SHA-1 hash object that you can update with data and finally get a digest. But you aren't saving that object. A new object is created and discarded for each chunk and then you create yet another empty digest and take its value. You are always hashing the same empty sequence and getting `da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709`.

Since you grab the entire document in a single `read` there is no advantage to writing it to a temporary file and doing chunked reads. Just hash the data that you grabbed.

```
def gen_hash():
    for attr, document in request.files.iteritems():
        orig_filename = document.filename
        new_doc = add_doc(orig_filename, orig_filename)
        mhash1 = sha1(document.read()).hexdigest()
        print mhash1
```

Assuming that `document` is a file like object, you can update the hash in chunks and avoid the memory costs of reading the entire document at once.

```
def gen_hash():
    for attr, document in request.files.iteritems():
        orig_filename = document.filename
        new_doc = add_doc(orig_filename, orig_filename)
        hash = sha1()
        for chunk in iter(lambda: document.read(65536), ''):
            hash.update(chunk)
        mhash1 = hash.hexdigest()
        print mhash1
```

When `iter` is called with 2 paramters, the first is a function that generates data and the second is an end condition for the iteration. So, `iter(lambda: document.read(65536), '')` keeps calling a function that reads data from `document` until there is nothing left.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped and saved me a day!

Comment: but will the code work for very large files say in size of few MB / GB i.e the code : mhash1 = sha1(document.read()).hexdigest()  ? reading at once

Comment: The potential memory buster is in your original code: `tmp1.write(document.read())`. If `document` is a file object or something else that doesn't already have the data in memory, then, yes, its a problem for large data. I'll update my answer.